# Migrating :odd selector behaviour after jQuery Depreciation

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter, selector, migrate

I am having issues migrating the last bit of our code to exit depreciation.
We use jQuery 3.6, and since jQuery 3.4 the `:odd` selector is depreciated.

> **As of jQuery 3.4**, the :odd pseudo-class is deprecated. Remove it from
> your selectors and filter the results later using .odd() (available in
> jQuery 3.5.0 or newer).

However, it appears to be very difficult to retain the background color for every 3rd row.

```css
.divGrey {
  background-color: #c0c0c0;
}
```

```js
$('.container').filter(function () {
  return $(this).children().length === 3;
}).filter(':odd').addClass('divGrey'); // :odd Depreciated
```

I can do `.odd().addClass('divGrey')` but I lose the background I want to retain for every third child. How can I do this? Do I need to remove filter function?

Any help appreciated - thanks!

Comment: You can also ditch js completely and use plain css for this. `:nth-child(3n)` for every third child.

Comment: @cloned I had the same thought, to use CSS alone for this, but I don't think it's possible to create the same logic. Note that the OP is looking to only select the odd indexed parent elements which have 3 child elements - not the children themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do what you require you can use the index argument provided to a function handler in `filter()` and return a boolean value to state if the element's index is even or odd, like this:

```js
$('.container').filter(i => i % 2).addClass('divGrey');
```

```css
.divGrey {
  background-color: #c0c0c0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">0</div>
<div class="container">1</div>
<div class="container">2</div>
<div class="container">3</div>
<div class="container">4</div>
<div class="container">5</div>
```

Note that I removed the first `filter()` call as it wasn't relevant to the question.